# Publishing Github packages for a monorepo as part of an organization

Tags: github, monorepo, github-package-registry

I have a Lerna monorepo on Github Enterprise which currently has two npm packages that I'm trying to publish to the Github package registry under the same repo.

For reference say they are:

- github.com/mycompany/package-a
- github.com/mycompany/package-b

I followed these instructions: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-multiple-packages-to-the-same-repository

So now my 2 package.json files look like the following (trimmed for formatting purposes):

```
"name": "@mycompany/package-a",
"repository": {
    "url": "ssh://git@github.com:mycompany/monorepo.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
```

```
"name": "@mycompany/package-b",
"repository": {
    "url": "ssh://git@github.com:mycompany/monorepo.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
```

So you can notice they both have the same URL for the repository as recommended.

**First problem:** One is that my company already has repos called `package-a` and `package-b`. It seems that you can't have a naming collision with a package in a monorepo and a package outside the monorepo.¹

**Second and more important problem:** <s>This doesn't seem to work for me at all. I renamed the package in their respective `package.json` files to avoid the naming collision to `package-a-mono` and `package-b-mono` which I don't really want to do but I'm just trying to get it to work. I get a 404 when trying to run either `lerna publish` or `npm publish` inside of the repos themselves. Like it's not actually trying to read that `repository.url` field in that it tells you to modify.</s>

^ This turned out to be temporary or was never actually an issue, it was just because of the naming conflicts.

npm publish output:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@mycompany%2fpackage-a - The expected resource was not found.
```

lerna publish output:

```
lerna http fetch PUT 404 https://npm.pkg.github.com/mycompany/@mycompany%2fpackage-a 327ms
lerna ERR! E404 The expected resource was not found.
```

Has anyone run into this and found a solution?

¹On a somewhat worse note, for some reason the very first time I ran this it actually did publish a package into the monorepo for `package-a`. But from then on I get the error `lerna ERR! E422 Package "package-a" is already associated with another repository.` Nothing changed and I couldn't publish another version to the same repo.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here was that we had repos in the organization with the same name as the package being published and it didn't like that.

When I looped back around to solving this I renamed the packages to not have a collision with another existing repo in the organization and it worked as expected.

Comment: This is pretty awkward. We have a package called "utilities" that holds utilities in various languages, one of which is node. Now we have to rename the node package so it's not just "@organization/utilities".

Comment: Is there any documentation on that rule? I've been running into the same issue.

Comment: @GN. I couldn't find any documentation on it originally (and I haven't been back through the documentation since), ended up solving just based on my observations and trial and error.

Answer (score 11):

Another possible cause of this error (discussed and ruled out in the original question body) is if any package's `package.json`'s repository field does not match the git URL of the repo - for example, if you transferred the repo to a different organisation, or renamed the repo, but didn't update every package's `package.json` with the new URL.

The error message will report 404 on `https://npm.pkg.github.com/@org/package-name` even if the problem is with the repository URL.

(credit to [jonas-reif's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618719/publishing-github-packages-for-a-monorepo-as-part-of-an-organization#comment107536714_59934341))

Comment: You saved me a couple of hours! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! After renaming the repo, I didn't realize I have to update the repository URL field. This is not obvious anywhere!

Comment: Many thanks for this. I might not have thought to look at the registry otherwise and found the typo.

Comment: I know I'm very late to this, but if someone stumbles upon the same problem:
`Another possible cause of this error ...) is if any package's package.json's repository field does not match the git URL of the repo`

This can be fixed by simply filling the "repository" field in `package.json` correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, I had to generate a new personal access token that had more privileges. Just `read:packages` and `write:packages` was not sufficient, you also needed `repo`.

Comment: what permissions did you add?

Comment: I can't confirme that. Tried to add an access token with all permissions with no luck...

Comment: For me I forgot to update my repository url in my package.json after renaming my repository...

Comment: With private repositories I've had problems with access tokens that only had package read / create privileges and needed to add repository privileges too, but I don't think it was related to this specific error.

Comment: +1 you do in fact get this very same 404 "resource not found" with the github npm URL shown in the error message when you don't have repo privileges.. very misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to add the following line to my NPM package's URL:

"repository": "https://github.com/ACCOUNT/REPOSITORY"

This repository was the root of my mono repository.

More on this here:
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#publishing-multiple-packages-to-the-same-repository